# How to override entity:link() function?

Tags: 8, navigation, entities

I have an entity with `entitylisthandler`.

In entitylisthandler, i have a function to build row like:

```
public function buildRow(EntityInterface $entity) {

    /* @var $entity \Drupal\mymodule\Entity\xyz*/
    $row['id'] = $entity->id();
    $row['config_name'] = $entity->link();
    //$row['first_name'] = $entity->first_name->value;
    $row['ctype'] = $entity->ctype->value;
    return $row + parent::buildRow($entity);
  }
```

In @line 3:

```
$row['config_name'] = $entity->link();
```

I'm calling link function here which calls entity `canonical` link.

**How to change this default value 'canonical' to some other link like 'delete-form'?**

This is the Drupal core link function which I'm trying to override in `entitylistbuilder` file.

```
public function link($text = NULL, $rel = 'delete-form', array $options = []) {
  return $this->toLink($text, $rel, $options)->toString();
  }
```

I have changed its argument from 'canonical' to 'delete-form', but it won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not change the core function. What core does, if $rel is not set, it uses 'canonical'. If you want to use 'delete-form' instead, put this as an argument when using the link function:

```
$row['config_name'] = $entity->link(NULL, 'delete-form');
```

BTW, link() is deprecated, so use toLink() instead.